# Good pattern for creating an object that supports interning?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I need a Class that supports interning, like Java's `String` class. When creating an instance of the Class it should return a pre-existing reference if a reference with the same parameters already exists. Otherwise it should return a new reference. Such that:

```
Foo a = new Foo(5);
Foo b = new Foo(5);
Foo c = new Foo(6);
a == b
a != c
```

1) Is it the job of a factory to maintain the table of pre-existing objects, or is the table  generally just a static variable within the class itself?

2) What is the table of pre-existing objects? Is it a Set of objects you search through every time an instance is requested, or is it a Map where keys are objects and values are parameters?

Comment: Have you looked at the source for `String`?

Comment: String appears to use native code for its intern method.

Comment: I'm curious: why would you *need* an object that supports interning?

Comment: @BrunoReis I have a pre-existing object graph in a database. I have an almost identical object graph in my program where objects are composed of the database objects. To reconstruct the database object graph with my own program object graph, some kind of object interning seemed to be the easiest approach. I may be very wrong.

Comment: How many 'parameters' are we talking about? If just one (or two), a static factory method coupled with `Map` (or `Map<K,Map<L,E>>`) should do the trick (or for thread safety, use `ConcurrentMap`). Will you need to consider class loading/unloading, such as when an application can be dynamically loaded/unloaded by a container? If so, then a `WeakHashMap` with `WeakReferences`. If several parameters, then **Pangea**'s suggestion of `Flyweight` + `ComputingMap` makes (a lot) more sense.

Comment: @BrunoReis because you have to store a hideously large set of data in memory and need to intern objects to allow all of the data to sit happily in memory rather than causing some sort of out-of-memory or heap-space errors, or massive GC slow-downs. If you don't want to use something like Guava's `Interner`, then you can create a `HashMap` (maybe a concurrent one) and always filter your objects through that map immediately after creation with something like: `interningMap.computeIfAbsent(object, Function.identity())`. Your object then must implement `hashCode` and `equals` per their contracts.

Answer (score 2):

Two things come to my mind

1. [Flyweight Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern)
2. [Guava's ComputingMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html)

Comment: Yes, the "flyweight" pattern description sounds exactly like the java concept of String interning, which is what the question was about. Technically, this answers the question (since it was about "pattern" rather than "implementation"). However, the link to "Guava's ComputingMap" is old and broken; the class no longer exists in guava, and there is no explanation of what it did or how to use it. The answer by @eric-pilz below gives more details about the guava `Interner` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If you can add a third-party dependency consider Google Guava and its [Interners](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Interners.html) class. It has two simple interners: a `WeakInterner` and a `StrongInterner`. The `StrongInterner` is backed by a `ConcurrentMap` and is best suited for a small, closed set of values. If you cannot control or in any way limit what is interned then you can opt for the `WeakInterner`, which relies on `WeakReference`s. The trade-off for using the `WeakInterner` is performance.

Comment: Nice! That works great. Too bad there isn't a non thread-safe version as well (I'm only ever using it in 1 thread). I guess setting the concurrency level to 1 will have to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with the `new` operator, which will not reuse an existing object. A factory is the best way to do this. (It can be as easy as a static `newInstance` method of the class.) The usual data structure for this is a Map of some sort (typically a HashMap). A Set would be much more expensive. Depending on the number of objects, you could just use an array. (I think this might be what Byte does.)

Note that not a String objects are interned automatically, and that when you call `intern`, it may return a different String instance. for instance, this code will print "false":

```
String a = new String("hello");
String b = new String("hello");
a.intern();
b.intern();
System.out.println(a == b ? "true" : "false");
```

Comment: So my Foo class would contain a `static Map<Foo,Integer> m` and `Foo newInstance(Integer i)` and I would check if `m.containsValue(i)`? It just seems odd that I have to maintain my parameter in two places (the object and the map).

Comment: But lines 3 and 4 aren't doing anything. Change them to `a = a.intern()` and `b = b.intern()` and it will return "true".

Comment: @cgull Line 3 does do something, just not to `a`. The point of this example (and perhaps I didn't make this clear) is that `new` will always return a distinct object, regardless of any kind of interning that may be set up.

Comment: @Jim - The only way to avoid creating a second copy of an object is to keep track of the objects you have created. Be aware, also, that the object may go out of scope. If you want the interned object to be available for garbage collection at that point, you can store a WeakReference to the object in the internment map.