# How do I use indexOf?

Tags: java

I have an array list called `itemList` which holds many items. Each item is of type RetailItem and holds a description, price, number in stock, and a product code. What I'm trying to do is search for the matching item in my array list using the `indexof` method, but i'm having trouble. Maybe I've been thinking too hard but it's been 2 hours since I started trying to figure this out.

I'm going to do other things in the program but first I have to find the matching item
Here's the snippet of code I can't figure out:

```
System.out.println("Enter UPC for an item you want, enter -1 when done");

    boolean found = false;
    do {
        System.out.print("\nEnter a UPC ");
        targetUPC = keyboard.nextLine();
        RetailItem temporary = new RetailItem("Default", 0, 0, targetUPC);

        System.out.println(targetUPC);
        int retval = itemList.indexOf(targetUPC);
        System.out.println("It's at index " + retval);
```

Edit: indexOf always returns a -1. For example, the first item in the itemList (which is an arrayList of RetailItems) is this: Corn Crisps,
                                       9.45,
35,
61835.

When I enter the UPC 61835, indexOf doesn't find it at index 0

Maybe I don't make sense, I might have to keep trying to figure it out

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: You're calling indexOf() with a String as argument, although your list contains instances of RetailItem? That's like searching a banana in a box of apples. Doesn't make any sense. A RetailItem can not be equal to a String. Only a String can be equal to a String. And only a RetailItem can be equal to a RetailItem.

Comment: Thanks everyone, but I was just and idiot and my equals method was using == and not .equals

Answer (score 0):

If you create a toString() function for your RetailItem class, then you could compare the strings because each Object will have a string representation. You can choose to have the object represented in a way that will match what you are looking for when a user enters a UPC.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what indexOf does: it iterates through the list, and tests if each `RetailItem` in the list is equal (using `equals()`) the the object passed as argument to `indexOf()`.

A RetailItem can't be equal to a String. And a String can't be equal to a RetailItem. So that can't possibly work.

So you need to iterate by yourself, to find the first RetailItem whose `targetUPC` is equal to the `targetUPC` entered by the user.

```
int index = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (list.get(i).getTargetUpc().equals(targetUpc) {
        index = i;
        break;
     }
}
```

Comment: A RetailItem's equals override can be coded in such a way that it could return true when given a string (the UPC) or another RetailItem... its just not exactly a good idea..

Comment: No it can't. equals() is supposed to be commutative: a.equals(b) iff b.equals(a). BTW, indexOf uses o.equals(listElement), so it would call equals() on the string.

Comment: the keywords there are 'supposed to be' not HAS to be, therefore a RetailItem CAN in fact equal a string, just not the other way around. So its only a bad idea, not impossible.

Comment: You can do everything you want with your code if the goal is to have bugs. Most of the time that's not what you want. So you respect the contract of the methods you're implementing. Sure equals() CAN be implemented with `return true;` as well by that logic.

Comment: Agreed, which is why its a bad idea... but again, not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using an ArrayList.

From the indexOf implementation:

```
public int indexOf(Object o) {
        if (o == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                if (elementData[i]==null)
                    return i;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
                    return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

As you can see, indexOf uses equals and comparing two different instances gives you a false.

You should use *interning* like in Java's String class. When creating an instance of the Class it should return a pre-existing reference if a reference with the same parameters already exists.

I'm not an expert on this, maybe you can find some help with this topic:
[Good pattern for creating an object that supports interning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035659/good-pattern-for-creating-an-object-that-supports-interning)

Hope this helps