# Java HashSet contains Object

Tags: java, object, equals, contains, hashset

I made my own class with an overridden equals method which just checks, if the names (attributes in the class) are equal. Now I store some instances of that class in a HashSet so that there are no instances with the same names in the HashSet.

My Question: How is it possible to check if the HashSet contains such an object. .contains() wont work in that case, because it works with the .equals() method. I want to check if it is really the same object.

edit:

```
package testprogram;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Example {
    private static final Set<Example> set = new HashSet<Example>();
    private final String name;
    private int example;

    public Example(String name, int example) {
        this.name = name;
        this.example = example;
        set.add(this);
    }

    public boolean isThisInList() {
        return set.contains(this);
        //will return true if this is just equal to any instance in the list
        //but it should not
        //it should return true if the object is really in the list
    }

    public boolean remove() {
        return set.remove(this);
    }

    //Override equals and hashCode
}
```

Sorry, my english skills are not very well. Please feel free to ask again if you don't understand what I mean.

Comment: You must override `hashCode()` when overriding `equals()`.

Comment: I know, but that's not my question.

Comment: This sounds more like a bad design that needs to be resolved than a specific implementation.

Comment: So, you have overrides for both method and it still does not work? What do you mean by "such an object"? Do you have some actual Object you are looking for?

Comment: @stonar96 Then your question is unclear.  Please update it to include the fact that have overridden `hashCode`.  But in that case `contains` should find your object.  Please also include any relevant code and data so that we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: If the `equals` you've written is too coarse, make it finer. Or leave `Object.equals` unoverridden.

Comment: I'm guessing here. To check the reference to an instance is the same you should use _interning_. I'm not an expert on this, i just can give a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035659/good-pattern-for-creating-an-object-that-supports-interning) if you are interested. If is this that you want maybe someone can give you an example.

Comment: I added some code, but I think my problem is solved with ==

Comment: Most objects should only have one sensible notion of equality.  If that's reference equality, then leave `equals` and `hashCode` not overridden.  It's weird to care about both reference equality and some other kind of equality.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Not in my case, because I have a HashSet, which should be synchron to a config file and the names should be unique. And in the class should also be a method like saveToConfigFile() and in this method I want to check if this instance is really in the HashSet. Otherwise I will probably write an object to the config file that is not in the HashSet anymore, but has the same name, than an object in the HashSet.

Comment: That still doesnt sound like reference equality is what you want, but rather something more like a Map on the names.

Comment: An example:
Example e = new Example("test", 1);
e.remove();
new Example("test", 1);

if I now use:
e.writeToConfigFile();
nothing should happen because e is not in the HashSet anymore and the == returns false but .contains() would return true, because there is another object in the list with the same name "test".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, the only way to tell if a particular instance of an object is contained in the HashSet, is to iterate the contents of the HashSet, and compare the object identities ( using the == operator instead of the equals() method).

Something like:

```
boolean isObjectInSet(Object object, Set<? extends Object> set) {
   boolean result = false;

   for(Object o : set) {
     if(o == object) {
       result = true;
       break;
     }
   }

   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way to check if objects are the same object is by comparing them with == to see that the object references are equal.

Kind Greetings,
Frank

Comment: Thank you, your answer is the answer of my question.

Answer (score 1):

try this.. 
Considering only one property 'name' of your Objects to maintain uniqueness.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + (name == null ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    User other = (User) obj;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to override the hashCode method also.

Answer (score 0):

HashSet `contains` uses the equals method to determine if the object is contained - and duplicates are not kept within the HashSet.

Assuming your `equals` and `hashcode` are only using a `name` field...

```
HashSet<MyObject> objectSet = new HashSet<MyObject>();
MyObject name1Object = new MyObject("name1");

objectSet.add(new MyObject("name1"));
objectSet.add(name1Object);
objectSet.add(new MyObject("name2"));
//HashSet now contains 2 objects, name1Object and the new name2 object
//HashSets do not hold duplicate objects (name1Object and the new object with name1 would be considered duplicates)

objectSet.contains(new MyObject("name1")) // returns true
objectSet.contains(name1Object)           // returns true
objectSet.contains(new MyObject("name2")) // returns true
objectSet.contains(new MyObject("name3")) // returns false
```

If you wanted to check if the object in the HashSet is the exact object you are comparing you would have to pull it out and compare it directly using `==`

```
for (MyObject o : objectSet)
{
    if (o == name1Object)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

If you do this alot for specific objects it might be easier to use a `HashMap` so you don't have to iterate through the list to grab a specific named Object. May be worth looking into for you because then you could do something like this:

```
(objectMap.get("name") == myNameObject) // with a HashMap<String, MyNameObject> where "name" is the key string.
```

Comment: I have another reference, and I want to check if it's still in the list. Do you know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

> I made my own class with an overridden equals method which just checks, if the names (attributes in the class) are equal.

This breaks the contract of [.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)), and you must never do it no matter how convenient it seems.

Instead, if you want to index and look up elements by a certain attribute such as the name, use a `HashMap<Name, YourType>` to find them. Alternatively, use a [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) and pass it a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that compares the name only. You can then remove the incorrect `equals` method.

There are then three ways  if you want to find objects by reference equality:

1. Your objects have no inherent or useful notion of equality.

   Don't implement `equals`. Leave it to its default. You can then use a `HashSet` to look for reference equality, and a HashMap or TreeSet to index them by any specific attributes.
2. Your objects do have a useful, universal notion of equality, but you want to find equivalent instances efficiently anyways.

   This is almost never the case. However, you can use e.g. an Apache [IdentityMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/map/IdentityMap.html).
3. You don't care about efficiency.

   Use a for loop and `==` every element.